# Change particular key in nested array to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If the fields key in a object is array, change the first value of arrays as a key value pair object in javascript.

```
var obj =
[
  { id:1, fields:["item", "2", "list"]},
  { id:2, fields:["sample", "1", "check"]}
]
function newObj(obj) {
        let objFields = {};
        modifiedObj.fields.forEach(field => objFields[field] = field);
        modifiedObj.fields= objFields;
        return modifiedObj; 

}
var result = this.newObject(obj)
```

Expected Output

```
  {
   item: "item",
   sample: "sample"
  }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, please explain in more details.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi thanks for reply, want filter to out `fields` key, create a object with first array value as key and value

Comment: It's still not clear what the value should be, for example, for the `item` key, should the value be the string `"item"` or a variable called `item`? In the second case, what does this variable contain?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi sorry, it should be string, updated expected output

Comment: @codecat please mark an answer as the solution for future visitors to benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var obj =
[
  { id:1, fields:["item", "2", "list"]},
  { id:2, fields:["sample", "1", "check"]}
]
function newObject(obj) {
        let objFields = {};
        obj.forEach(e => {
          if(e.fields && e.fields.length>0)
            objFields[e.fields[0]] = e.fields[0];
        });
        return objFields; 
}
var result = this.newObject(obj);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional approach that makes use of [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the object you need.

```js
const input = [
    { id: 1, fields: ["item", "2", "list"] },
    { id: 2, fields: ["sample", "1", "check"] }
];

const process = (input) => (Object.assign(...input.map(({ fields }) => (
    fields.length ? { [fields[0]]: fields[0] } : {}
))));

console.log(process(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet was close, you just needed to clean up the variable names, and then using `map` makes it a bit neater too:

```js
const obj = [
  {id: 1, fields: ["item", "2", "list"]},
  {id: 2, fields: ["sample", "1", "check"]}
]

function newObj(inputArray) {
  let outputObject = {};
  inputArray.map(item => item.fields[0])
            .forEach(field => outputObject[field] = field);
  return outputObject;
}

var result = newObj(obj)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks for help, how to get output like {fields: "item", fields: "sample"} if the fields  value is array

Comment: You can't have an object like `{fields: "item", fields: "sample"}` in JS as those field names are duplicates.
Give me an actual example of what output you want for a specific input and I'll change the code to match

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/miyavv/vu0zymLe/3/ if possible please help, scenario mentioned in fiddle comment

Comment: As above, your "Expected Output" is not possible as the object field names (keys) need to be unique. In the comment in that fiddle, "info" is repeated twice and so is "cities"

Comment: thanks fr reply, updted my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/miyavv/vu0zymLe/11/